# Trying to restrict access to a route if loggedIn condition is true

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to restrict access to the login if the user is already logged in by checking if there is already a token in the localStorage. Any idea on how I can fix it ?

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

import Login from "./pages/auth/Login";
import Register from "./pages/auth/Register";
import Forgot from "./pages/auth/Forgot";
import Home from "./pages/landing/Home";
import Team from "./pages/landing/Team";
import Prices from "./pages/landing/Prices";

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        { path: "/", redirect: "/home" },
        { path: "/login", component: Login },
        { path: "/register", component: Register },
        { path: "/forgot", component: Forgot },
        { path: "/home", component: Home },
        { path: "/team", component: Team },
        { path: "/prices", component: Prices },
    ],
});

const loggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem("token");
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.name !== "Login" && !loggedIn) next({ name: "Login" });
    else next("./home");
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, for unauthenticated users the guard will behave as expected, after the user is logged in, every route is redirected to "/home". Instead, you should call `next()` without options, and let the router navigate to initial location.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.name !== "Login" && !loggedIn) next({ name: "Login" });
    else next();
});
```

Also, since it seems that you are using `vue-router` v4, you can dump `next` argument (it is deprecated now) and just return the route.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
    if (to.name !== "Login" && !loggedIn) return { name: "Login" };
});
```

Also, as a side note, `next("./home")` does not look right. It is not a path but a url: `next("/home")`

Answer (score 1):

just you can add a middleware to your route like this:

```
Route::get('/login',[CustomAuthController::class,'login'])->middleware('alreadyLoggedIn');
```

and this is a middleware example:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Session()->has('loginId') && (url('login')==$request->url()|| url('registration')
    ==$request->url())){
        return back();
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for route :

```
Route::get('login',[AuthController::class,'login'])->middleware('CurrentlyLoggedIn');
```

Sample code for middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CurrentlyLoggedIn
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(session()->has('loginId')
            && (url('login') == $request->url() || url('registration') == $request->url())){
            return back();
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```